# Sendindg strings with pipes and using signal in C?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, signals

I have to do a program in C on Linux as a homework.
*(Thanks to the online lectures, my teacher didn't give us the example programs)*

There's a Parent and two children.

The First child has to send Strings to the Parent using Pipe.
Then the Parent has to send Strings to the other child using pipe.
In the end, Other child has to Signal back to the parent.

Can someone show me a very simplified code for this?
- I can't find easy examples and descriptions.

Comment: No. I wrote here because it is much more easy for me. - Course I googled it, and the very few I found was over complicated and didn't describe the important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a bidirectional pipe.
A pipe is a unidirectional method of ipc, but you can easly create a bidirectional pipe using two pipes.
Now for create a pipe you use the pipe() function (https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe for documentation).
I can give you some information about pipe() , the first argument is a two fild int array, if the pipe return a value different from -1 the call terminate sucesfully and at the position 0 of this array you have a file descriptor where you can use read for read the contents of the pipe and at position 1 you can use write for write on the pipe.
Some time ago i write for exercise a bidirectional pipe, so i can give you this code like an example, but off course read the documentation and understand what is a pipe and cetera.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int
main(void){
  int parents_fields[2];
  int child_fields[2];

  int parent_char;
  int child_char;
  char char_to_write;

  setbuf(stdout,NULL);

  if(pipe(parents_fields) == -1){
    perror("pipe() : parent_fields");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(pipe(child_fields) == -1){
    perror("pipe() : child_fields");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  switch(fork()){
  case -1:  // In case of error
    perror("fork() failed, terminating the program");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  case 0:   // Child
    // Closing unused file descriptors
    if(close(parents_fields[1]) == -1){
      perror("Child: Error closing parents_fields[1], terminatin the program");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(close(child_fields[0]) == -1){
      perror("Child: Error closing child_fields[0], terminatin the program");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read(parents_fields[0],&parent_char,1) == -1){
      perror("Child: Error reading the parent pipe, terminating the program");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%c\n",parent_char);

    parent_char = toupper(parent_char);

    printf("%c\n",parent_char);

    if(write(child_fields[1],&parent_char,1) == -1){
      printf("Child: Error reading the child pipe, terminating the program , %d , %d",child_fields[1],errno);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    break;

  default:  //parent
    scanf("%c",&char_to_write);
    // Closing unused file descriptors
    if(close(parents_fields[0] == -1)){
      perror("Parent: Closing parents_fields[0], terminating the program...");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(close(child_fields[1]) == -1){
      printf("Parent: Error closing child_fields[1], terminatin the program, %d",child_fields[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(parents_fields[1],&char_to_write,1) == -1){
      perror("Parent: Error writing on parent pipe");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read(child_fields[0],&parent_char,1) == -1){
      perror("Child: Error reading the child pipe, terminating the program");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%c\n",parent_char);

    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind telling what your code supposed to do?

Comment: You are welcome. The parent use a pipe for send to the child a characther (char_to_write) and the child read this characther and use the toupper function for transform it into an uppercase character, after this, the child send it to the parent through a pipe and the parent print the upper case characther sended from the child.

Comment: For me, it takes the char and prints it 3 times with lowercase.

Comment: I tried to run it. and if i write a, it stamps :   a A A, but the point is that it use a bidirectional pipe for send a character to the child, and viceversa

Comment: This isn't a bidirectional pipe. It's two unidirectional pipes. If you want a real bidirectional pipe, use `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds);`

Comment: I said up that a pipe is always unidirectional, but i said bidirectional for "abstraction" and with socketpair you create with unix socket a data structure equivalent to a stream pipe not a stream pipe.

Comment: If you can use the word "abstraction" to say a thing is something that it really isn't, then a UNIX socket is a pipe by "abstraction" too. You can't say that your thing is a bidirectional pipe and that mine isn't. (And in any case, my solution works like one but yours doesn't.)

Comment: Unix socket and pipe are different data structure, the answer was about pipes not unix socket, i use the term bidirectional pipe for say a data structure build on top of two unidirectional pipe, my solution for the problem works good for this problem and, you can't say for "abstraction" that a unix socket is a pipe. Into the linux programming interface the writer use the term bidirectional pipe for identify a data structure build on top of two pipes, and i say into the post that you can easly create a bidirectional pipe using two pipes, i don't see any problem there.